# How can I prevent \mathclap from quadrupling \stepcounter

Tags: counters, mathtools

When I want to iterate a counter using `\stepcounter` inside `\mathllap`
, `\mathclap` or `\mathrlap` the counter iterates by 4 instead of by 1. E.g, the following MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcounter{mycounter}


\begin{document}
$\mathclap{\stepcounter{mycounter}xyz}$

\arabic{mycounter}
\end{document}
```

outputs

xyz
  4

while

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcounter{mycounter}


\begin{document}
\stepcounter{mycounter}$\mathclap{xyz}$

\arabic{mycounter}
\end{document}
```

outputs the desired

xyz
  1

as expected.

In this simple example the second MWE is an easy work-around, but how can I deal with this problem in a more elegant ways, when it is not so easy to move the `\stepcounter` outside of the `\mathclap` like in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcounter{mycounter}
\newcommand{\printMyNextCounter}{\stepcounter{mycounter}\arabic{mycounter}}


\begin{document}
$\mathclap{\printMyNextCounter xyz}$

\printMyNextCounter
\end{document}
```

outputs

2xyz
   5

I think this can be almost seen as a bug. Would it be possible to fix this bug?

Comment: it isn't a bug mathclap content is always evaluated 4 times

Comment: I personally think it would be more user-friendly if mathclap would only effect the spacing and not stuff like counters. Probably it was much easier to implement mathclap such that it is internally evaluated 4 times, but for the end-user the side-effects of the four evaluations are not beneficial but rather annoying. Or would you tell me that if both implementations were equally easy and would result in exactly the same spacing behavior, you would still prefer that everything is evaluated four times? Maybe someone has an idea for a future implementation that does not need 4 times evaluation?

Comment: You need 4 evaluations that;s the way tex works (you would see the same with `\textrm{..}` and lots of other commands, what is possible (but somewhat costly) is to save and restore all counters at each evaluation (tabularx does that when doing trial layouts) It is really very rare to be doing anything more complicated than `x=0` in a \mathclap certainly counters I have never seen. If you separate out your increment and printing and only have the printing part in the mathclap then it will work better, if you really need the set reset all counters version I could post an answer later probably

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can inject in `\mathclap` the same trickery that `amsmath` uses for avoiding the issue within `\text` and related commands such as `\textrm` and similar.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\MHInternalSyntaxOn
%%% original definitions
%\def\MT_mathllap:Nn #1#2{{}\llap{$\m@th#1{#2}$}}
%\def\MT_mathrlap:Nn #1#2{{}\rlap{$\m@th#1{#2}$}}
%\def\MT_mathclap:Nn #1#2{{}\clap{$\m@th#1{#2}$}}
%%% modified definitions
\def\MT_mathllap:Nn #1#2{{}\llap{$\check@choice{#1}\m@th#1{#2}$}}
\def\MT_mathrlap:Nn #1#2{{}\rlap{$\check@choice{#1}\m@th#1{#2}$}}
\def\MT_mathclap:Nn #1#2{{}\clap{$\check@choice{#1}\m@th#1{#2}$}}
\MHInternalSyntaxOff

\makeatletter
\def\check@choice#1{\ifx#1\displaystyle\firstchoice@true\else\firstchoice@false\fi}
\makeatother

\newcounter{mycounter}

\begin{document}

$\mathclap{\stepcounter{mycounter}xyz}$

\arabic{mycounter}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 and you'll probably get the tick which is so depressing

Comment: Would you recommend me using this by default in all my LaTeX documents or do you think this slows down the compilation significantly or do you see any danger of incompatibilities?

Comment: @Jakob I'm not sure I'd increment a counter inside `\mathclap`, actually. The slow down is not significant.

Answer (score 4):

You can arrange the counter is reset in each of the four evaluations

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcounter{mycounter}
\newcounter{mycounterx}
\newcommand{\printMyNextCounter}{\stepcounter{mycounter}\arabic{mycounter}}
\newcommand\mymathclap[1]{%
\setcounter{mycounterx}{\value{mycounter}}%
\mathclap{\setcounter{mycounter}{\value{mycounterx}}#1}%
}

\begin{document}
$\mymathclap{\printMyNextCounter xyz}$

\printMyNextCounter
\end{document}
```

The four evaluations come from the `\mathchoice` primitive and you see the same with most box commands in math mode that needs to react to being in a subscript and change size, `\sqrt`, `\phantom` etc would all have the same issue as `\mathclap` here.

Comment: `\text` and `\textrm` don't have the problem.

Comment: @egreg you know something told me that was wrong but I was tired:-) I'll delete those two, thanks

Answer (score 2):

The dirty trick follows. The TeX primitive `\mathchoice` is redefined:

```
\let\orimathchoice=\mathchoice
\def\mathchoice#1#2#3#4{\orimathchoice{#1}{\noadvance#2}{\noadvance#3}{\noadvance#4}}
\def\noadvance{\def\stepcounter##1{}}

% your code:

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcounter{mycounter}
\newcommand{\printMyNextCounter}{\stepcounter{mycounter}\arabic{mycounter}}

\begin{document}
$\mathclap{\printMyNextCounter xyz}$

\printMyNextCounter
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why is this trick dirty? I don't really understand it? Does it locally define `\stepcounter` to have no effect inside `\mathchoice`? How can you guarantee that `\stepcounter` has exactly once an effect?

Comment: @Jakob Yes, `\stepcounter` is locally re-defined in T, S and SS branches. Moreover, `\stepcounter` is processed only once in D branch of the `\mathchoice`. The `\mathchoice` TeX primitive creates four math lists `\mathchoice{D}{T}{S}{SS}` and uses only one in the second step of math processing. The `\mathclap` macro uses the `\matchoice` primitive and copies its parameter four times to the parameters of `\mathchoice`. This is reason of your problems: the `\matchoice` processes all its four parameters.

Comment: Do you know what are the pros and cons compared to egreg's solution: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/556803/128042 I think your solution would generalize to `\sqrt`, `\phantom` and so on? egreg's solution would also work with other iterators instead of \stepcounter?

Comment: The advantage of my solution (as all my solutions in stack.exchange) is that it is LaTeX independent. It does not use any package and not depends on LaTeX macros. My solution uses low-level approach: TeX primitives. Disadvantage: this solution solves only usage of `\stepcounter` macro in parameters of macros which are using `\mathchoice`. And the `\stepcounter` must be used before printing the counter in such parameter. The reverse usage: `\mathclap{print counter, step counter}` needs to keep SS branch and do redefinition in D, T and S branches.

Comment: You are true that this problem is something like bug. I'v reported (to TeX implementors) that `\mathchoice` idea is not so good idea by D. Knuth and that this problem can be solved much better. But this needs a deep re-implementation of TeX. Moreover, all `\mathchioce` dance is here only because of atypical syntax of fractions and generalized fractions (`\over` primitive etc.) which is generally not used by LaTeX users (they are using `\frac` macro).